# Send Key in AutoHotKey without recursion

Tags: autohotkey

I want to override <kbd>F1</kbd> but use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as <kbd>F1</kbd>

Okay what does this mean?
I want to override <kbd>F1</kbd> with my personal AHK command

```
F1::Run C:\..\foo.exe
```

But there are apps where I need the default <kbd>F1</kbd> key. Would it be possible to do something like

```
+F1:: Send {F1}
```

**without** the recursion to my first hotkey?
In other words: Send a key without triggering existing AHK shortcuts.

I hope it is clear what I'm asking for! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `#UseHook` directive to achieve this.

```
#UseHook, On

F1::    
    ; Your code...
    msgBox, Code!
return

+F1::Send, {F1}
```

> By default, hotkeys that use the keyboard hook cannot be triggered by means of the Send command.

You can read more about exactly what it does here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm

If you only want this effect on certain keys you can omit `#UseHook` and instead prefix your keys with a `$` symbol.

You can read more about the dollar-prefix here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar

```
$F1::    
    ; Your code...
    msgBox, Code!
return

+F1::Send, {F1}
```

Comment: Prefixing your hotkey with `$` is a less-drastic way of doing the same. http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar

Comment: @Dane Great point, I'll add that to the answer!